# Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?

Tags: python, operators, conditional-operator

Is there a [ternary conditional operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Python) in Python?

Comment: Though Pythons older than 2.5 are slowly drifting to history, here is a list of old pre-2.5 ternary operator tricks: ["Python Idioms", search for the text 'Conditional expression'](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PythonIdioms) .
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Python) is also quite helpful Ж:-)

Comment: In the Python 3.0 official documentation referenced in a comment above, this is referred to as "conditional_expressions" and is very cryptically defined.  That documentation doesn't even include the term "ternary", so you would be hard-pressed to find it via Google unless you knew exactly what to look for.  The [version 2 documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) is somewhat more helpful and includes a link to ["PEP 308"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/), which includes a lot of interesting historical context related to this question.

Comment: "ternary" (having three inputs) is a consequential property of this impelmentation, not a defining property of the concept. eg:  SQL has `case [...] { when ... then ...} [ else ... ] end` for a similar effect but not at all ternary.

Comment: also ISO/IEC 9899 (the C programming language standard) section 6.5.15 calls it the "the condtitional operator"

Comment: Wikipedia covers this thoroughly in the article "[?:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Python)".

Comment: It is mentioned here https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator, but not mentioned in Python Standard Library

Comment: In the years since nobar's comment the [conditional expression documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) has been updated to say _Conditional expressions (sometimes called a “ternary operator”)..._

Comment: As of 2020 the comprehensive answer is in the ['Ternary Operators'](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) documentation: "*Ternary operators are more commonly known as conditional expressions [...] they became a part of Python in version 2.4.*"

Comment: It's also useful to use the logical `or` operator, such as `x = a or b`

Comment: I have done the [translation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1537081/Есть-ли-в-python-тернарный-условный-оператор) of this question on ruSO.

Answer (score 9116, accepted):

Yes, it was [added](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html) in version 2.5. The expression syntax is:

```py
a if condition else b
```

First `condition` is evaluated, then exactly one of either `a` or `b` is evaluated and returned based on the [Boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) value of `condition`. If `condition` evaluates to `True`, then `a` is evaluated and returned but `b` is ignored, or else when `b` is evaluated and returned but `a` is ignored.

This allows short-circuiting because when `condition` is true only `a` is evaluated and `b` is not evaluated at all, but when `condition` is false only `b` is evaluated and `a` is not evaluated at all.

For example:

```py
>>> 'true' if True else 'false'
'true'
>>> 'true' if False else 'false'
'false'
```

Note that conditionals are an *expression*, not a *statement*. This means you can't use **statements** such as `pass`, or assignments with `=` (or "augmented" assignments like `+=`), within a conditional **expression**:

```py
>>> pass if False else pass
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pass if False else pass
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> # Python parses this as `x = (1 if False else y) = 2`
>>> # The `(1 if False else x)` part is actually valid, but
>>> # it can't be on the left-hand side of `=`.
>>> x = 1 if False else y = 2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: cannot assign to conditional expression

>>> # If we parenthesize it instead...
>>> (x = 1) if False else (y = 2)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    (x = 1) if False else (y = 2)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(In 3.8 and above, the `:=` "walrus" operator allows simple assignment of values *as an expression*, which is then compatible with this syntax. But please don't write code like that; it will quickly become very difficult to understand.)

Similarly, because it is an expression, the `else` part is *mandatory*:

```
# Invalid syntax: we didn't specify what the value should be if the 
# condition isn't met. It doesn't matter if we can verify that
# ahead of time.
a if True
```

You can, however, use conditional expressions to assign a variable like so:

```py
x = a if True else b
```

Or for example to return a value:

```
# Of course we should just use the standard library `max`;
# this is just for demonstration purposes.
def my_max(a, b):
    return a if a > b else b
```

Think of the conditional expression as switching between two values. We can use it when we are in a 'one value or another' situation, where we will *do the same thing* with the result, regardless of whether the condition is met. We use the expression to compute the value, and then do something with it. If you need to *do something different* depending on the condition, then use a normal `if` **statement** instead.

---

Keep in mind that it's frowned upon by some Pythonistas for several reasons:

- The order of the arguments is different from those of the classic `condition ? a : b` ternary operator from many other languages (such as [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29), [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B), [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29), [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29), [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), etc.), which may lead to bugs when people unfamiliar with Python's "surprising" behaviour use it (they may reverse the argument order).
- Some find it "unwieldy", since it goes contrary to the normal flow of thought (thinking of the condition first and then the effects).
- Stylistic reasons. (Although the 'inline `if`' can be *really* useful, and make your script more concise, it really does complicate your code)

If you're having trouble remembering the order, then remember that when read aloud, you (almost) say what you mean. For example, `x = 4 if b > 8 else 9` is read aloud as `x will be 4 if b is greater than 8 otherwise 9`.

Official documentation:

- [Conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)
- [Is there an equivalent of C’s ”?:” ternary operator?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator)

Comment: The order may seems strange for coders however `f(x) = |x| = x if x > 0 else -x` sounds very natural to mathematicians. You may also understand it as do A in most case, except when C then you should do B instead...

Comment: Be careful with order of operations when using this. For example, the line `z = 3 + x if x < y else y`. If `x=2` and `y=1`, you might expect that to yield 4, but it would actually yield 1. `z = 3 + (x if x > y else y)` is the correct usage.

Comment: The point was if you want to perform additional evaluations *after* the conditional is evaluated, like adding a value to the result, you'll either need to add the additional expression to both sides (`z = 3 + x if x < y else 3 + y`), or group the conditional (`z = 3 + (x if x < y else y)` or `z = (x if x < y else y) + 3`)

Comment: what if there are multiple conditions ?

Comment: @MrGeek, you could group the boolean expressions.
"foo" if (bool or bool && bool or etc) else "bar"

Comment: @Dimesio I meant something like if (c1) a1 elif (c2) a2 elif ... else a(n).

Comment: @MrGeek, I see what you mean, so you would basically be nesting the operations:
` "foo" if Bool else ("bar" if Bool else "foobar") `

Comment: Programmers need precise correct formulation even more than mathematician, because in mathematics there is always a resort to underlying concepts. A convincing argument  is the % operator, mimicking the way "mod" is used in math would have been a disaster.  So no, I don't accept your argument. It is like adhering to imperial units. Groetjes Albert

Comment: For the expression: 'x and y' and 'x or y' and their return values I recommend checking https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations and also the other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181901/python-boolean-expression-and-or/3181946#3181946

Comment: @KalZekdor I read that and expected 1... It took me a few seconds to see how you had to read it to make 4 a possibility.

Comment: Nice explanation, but short circuiting doesn't mean what you think it means - it means that the rest of the *condition* isn't evaluated if the 'truthiness' of the entire condition can be decided early. Statement 'b' is never evaluated even in languages without short circuiting.  Ex: if (arr != null && arr[0] = 1)...

Comment: As of Python 3.8+ this may not be entirely true. The walrus operator does allow assignments within expressions. Consider for instance a tiny example: `a if (a := len([1,2])) > 1 else -1` as opposed to writing: `len([1, 2]) if len([1, 2]) > 1 else -1`.

Comment: @Chris I edited to add a note about `:=` and to add detail on what actually happens when trying to use `=` in a conditional expression. Honestly it's a pretty bad idea to write conditional expressions like that; much clearer to assign `a` first, since that will happen as a side effect anyway.

Comment: Good answer, however, that syntax looks horrible to me. They should have implemented it the C# way `result = condition ? conditiontrue_expression : conditionfalse_expression` instead of abusing `if` for that.  `If` doesn't look like an operator at all.

Comment: You can put None to the ternary operator instead of pass and it's done. I use it very often

Comment: Python tries to avoid symbolic operators where possible. `if` may not look enough like an operator to *you*, but `... ? ... : ...` assumes familiarity with C to make any real sense.

Comment: @arioboo That's fine, if `None` is a valid result of the expression. Usually, you should just use a regular `if` statement in that case.

Answer (score 1000):

You can index into a tuple:

```
(falseValue, trueValue)[test]
```

`test` needs to return *True* or *False*.
It might be safer to always implement it as:

```
(falseValue, trueValue)[test == True]
```

or you can use the built-in [`bool()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#bool) to assure a [Boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) value:

```
(falseValue, trueValue)[bool(<expression>)]
```

Comment: Note that this one always evaluates everything, whereas the if/else construct only evaluates the winning expression.

Comment: `(lambda: print("a"), lambda: print("b"))[test==true]()`

Comment: It should be noted that what's within the `[]`s can be an arbitrary expression. Also, for safety you can explicitly test for truthiness by writing `[bool(<expression>)]`. The `bool()` function has been around since v2.2.1.

Comment: Is this idiomatic in python? Seems confusing but maybe its convention

Comment: Ugly is in the eye of the beholder, and I don't find this ugly at all.  It concisely make elegant use of the fact that bool is a subclass of int and that Python indexes are 0-based.  Admittedly, it's probably not the most efficient (as @SilverBackNet mentioned, both options are eval'd).  However, this works perfectly for deciding between 1 of 2 strings as @Claudiu said - I use it for this all the time.  For example: `'%d item%s to process!'%(num_items,('','s')[num_items > 1])` or `'Null hypothesis %s be rejected (p-val = %0.4f)'%(("can't",'must')[pval<alpha],pval)`.

Comment: I've done a similar trick -- only once or twice, but done it -- by indexing into a dictionary with `True` and `False` as the keys:  `{True:trueValue, False:falseValue}[test]`  I don't know whether this is any less efficient, but it does at least avoid the whole "elegant" vs. "ugly" debate.  There's no ambiguity that you're dealing with a boolean rather than an int.

Comment: [comparisons to singletons should always use is/is not instead of ==](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Comment: This trick may help avoid timing based attacks on algorithms if it always evaluates both possible results and avoids skipping code (an 'if' skips).

Comment: @jskulski only in old python, before 2.5.  Even then though, `if cond: [expression_1] else: [expression_2]` was more common

Comment: It's a "cool" and interesting idea, no doubt. But real-life code should be easy to read and least error-prone. If one of my developers used this I would ask him to change it. Since IMHO this should not be used in production code, I have down voted the answer.

Comment: @JDM there's no ambiguity since `bool` is actually a subclass of `int`.  And I'd argue that this answer and your variant of it are *both* ugly.

Comment: @MarkRansom, no argument that both are ugly (and no longer necessary) workarounds.  However the answer does have a garden-path issue that my variation avoids.  Put a tuple index in front of most anyone and I guarantee they will *not* immediately think, "oh, that variable must be representing a true/false value."  They'll start by assuming it's an ordinal number and only after puzzling over the context will they realize its actual purpose.  *That's* the ambiguity I'm talking about.

Answer (score 435):

For versions prior to 2.5, there's the trick:

```
[expression] and [on_true] or [on_false]
```

It can give wrong results when `on_true` has a false Boolean value.<sup>1</sup>

Although it does have the benefit of evaluating expressions left to right, which is clearer in my opinion.

<sub>1. [Is there an equivalent of C’s ”?:” ternary operator?](http://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator)</sub>

Comment: The remedy is to use (test and [true_value] or [false_value])[0], which avoids this trap.

Comment: Ternary operator usually executes faster(sometimes by 10-25%).

Comment: @volcano Do you have source for me?

Comment: @OrangeTux [Here's the disassembled code](https://tio.run/##bcoxCoAwEETRPqeY0kCwsPQ2kmR1QZOwWQtPH4OClQO/GV65dMtpao2PkkURuBoTIoEG76AOZGeDPol6SoKCCR5xrxH0yvVfeiwpdJ/lgVzH3kDWFOGk37Ha1m4). Using the method ThomasH suggested would be even slower.

Comment: Why you say "for versions  prior to 2.5"? This works under 3.12.1 for me.

Comment: "It can give wrong results when on_true has a false Boolean value" -> an example being `True and "" or "hello"` which returns `"hello"` instead of `""`. This is because `and` returns the first operand if it is False, otherwise it returns the second. Being True True, it returns `""`. Now we have `"" or "hello"`. The hello operator returns the first operand if it is True, otherwise it returns the second. Being `""` False, it returns `"hello"`.

Answer (score 358):

`<expression 1> if <condition> else <expression 2>`

```py
a = 1
b = 2

1 if a > b else -1 
# Output is -1

1 if a > b else -1 if a < b else 0
# Output is -1
```

Comment: This one emphasizes the primary intent of the ternary operator: value selection. It also shows that more than one ternary can be chained together into a single expression.

Comment: @Craig , I agree, but it's also helpful to know what will happen when there are no parentheses. In real code, I too would tend to insert explicit parens.

Comment: Use: `return 3 if t > 10 else t/2`

Answer (score 207):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

> Conditional expressions (sometimes called a “ternary operator”) have the lowest priority of all Python operations.
>
> The expression `x if C else y` first evaluates the condition, *C* (*not x*); if *C* is true, *x* is evaluated and its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and its value is returned.
>
> See [PEP 308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) for more details about conditional expressions.

New since version 2.5.

Answer (score 181):

An operator for a conditional expression in Python was added in 2006 as part of [Python Enhancement Proposal 308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/). Its form differs from common `?:` operator and it looks like this:

```
<expression1> if <condition> else <expression2>
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if <condition>: <expression1> else: <expression2>
```

Here is an example:

```
result = x if a > b else y
```

Another syntax which can be used (compatible with versions before 2.5):

```
result = (lambda:y, lambda:x)[a > b]()
```

where operands are [lazily evaluated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

Another way is by indexing a tuple (which isn't consistent with the conditional operator of most other languages):

```
result = (y, x)[a > b]
```

or explicitly constructed dictionary:

```
result = {True: x, False: y}[a > b]
```

Another (less reliable), but simpler method is to use `and` and `or` operators:

```
result = (a > b) and x or y
```

however this won't work if `x` would be `False`.

A possible workaround is to make `x` and `y` lists or tuples as in the following:

```
result = ((a > b) and [x] or [y])[0]
```

or:

```
result = ((a > b) and (x,) or (y,))[0]
```

If you're working with dictionaries, instead of using a ternary conditional, you can take advantage of [`get(key, default)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), for example:

```
shell = os.environ.get('SHELL', "/bin/sh")
```

<sup>Source: [?: in Python at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Python)</sup>

Comment: `result = {1: x, 0: y}[a > b]` is another possible variant (`True` and `False` are actually integers with values `1` and `0`)

Comment: It's wired that Expression comes first before the condition. After some practice, I can remember it now.

Answer (score 123):

Unfortunately, the

```
(falseValue, trueValue)[test]
```

solution doesn't have short-circuit behaviour; thus both `falseValue` and `trueValue` are evaluated regardless of the condition. This could be suboptimal or even buggy (i.e. both `trueValue` and `falseValue` could be methods and have side effects).

One solution to this would be

```
(lambda: falseValue, lambda: trueValue)[test]()
```

(execution delayed until the winner is known ;)), but it introduces inconsistency between callable and non-callable objects. In addition, it doesn't solve the case when using properties.

And so the story goes - choosing between three mentioned solutions is a trade-off between having the short-circuit feature, using at least Python 2.5 (IMHO, not a problem anymore) and not being prone to "`trueValue`-evaluates-to-false" errors.

Comment: While the tuple of lambdas trick works, it takes roughly 3x as long as the ternary operator.  It's only likely to be a reasonable idea if it can replace a long chain of `if else if`.

Comment: this is so unreadable compared with the ternary operator

Answer (score 106):

### **Ternary operator in different programming languages**

Here I just try to show some important differences in the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) between a couple of programming languages.

#### *Ternary operator in [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)*

```
var a = true ? 1 : 0;
# 1
var b = false ? 1 : 0;
# 0
```

#### *Ternary operator in [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29)*

```
a = true ? 1 : 0
# 1
b = false ? 1 : 0
# 0
```

#### *Ternary operator in [Scala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29)*

```
val a = true ? 1 | 0
# 1
val b = false ? 1 | 0
# 0
```

#### *Ternary operator in [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) programming*

```
a <- if (TRUE) 1 else 0
# 1
b <- if (FALSE) 1 else 0
# 0
```

#### *Ternary operator in Python*

```
a = 1 if True else 0
# 1
b = 1 if False else 0
# 0
```

Comment: This [blogger found python's ternary operator to be unnecessarily different than most other languages](https://archive.is/yqwSh).

Comment: It may sound opinionated; but what it essentially says is that it the Python syntax is likely to be understood by a person who never saw a ternary operator, while very few people will understand the more usual syntax unless they have been told first what it means.

Comment: Algol68:  a=.if. .true. .then. 1 .else. 0 .fi. This may be expressed also a=(.true.|1|0)  As usual Algol68 is an improvement over its successors.

Comment: something simple as `print a || '<alt text>'` in ruby is pita in python `print a if a is not None else 'alt text'`

Comment: @VarunGarg But of course you can say `print(a or 'alt text')` in Python.

Answer (score 85):

For Python 2.5 and newer there is a specific syntax:

```
[on_true] if [cond] else [on_false]
```

In older Pythons, a ternary operator is not implemented but it's possible to simulate it.

```
cond and on_true or on_false
```

Though there is a potential problem, which is if `cond` evaluates to `True` and `on_true` evaluates to `False` then `on_false` is returned instead of `on_true`. If you want this behaviour the method is OK, otherwise use this:

```
{True: on_true, False: on_false}[cond is True] # is True, not == True
```

which can be wrapped by:

```
def q(cond, on_true, on_false)
    return {True: on_true, False: on_false}[cond is True]
```

and used this way:

```
q(cond, on_true, on_false)
```

It is compatible with all Python versions.

Comment: The behaviour is not identical - `q("blob", on_true, on_false)` returns `on_false`, whereas `on_true if cond else on_false` returns `on_true`. A workaround is to replace `cond` with `cond is not None` in these cases, although that is not a perfect solution.

Comment: Why not `bool(cond)` instead of `cond is True`?  The former checks the truthiness of `cond`, the latter checks for pointer-equality with the `True` object.  As highlighted by @AndrewCecil, `"blob"` is truthy but it `is not True`.

Answer (score 59):

You might often find

```py
cond and on_true or on_false
```

but this leads to a problem when on_true == 0

```py
>>> x = 0
>>> print x == 0 and 0 or 1
1
>>> x = 1
>>> print x == 0 and 0 or 1
1
```

Where you would expect this result for a normal ternary operator:

```py
>>> x = 0
>>> print 0 if x == 0 else 1
0
>>> x = 1
>>> print 0 if x == 0 else 1
1
```

Answer (score 54):

> ## Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?

Yes. From the [grammar file](https://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html):

```py
test: or_test ['if' or_test 'else' test] | lambdef
```

The part of interest is:

```py
or_test ['if' or_test 'else' test]
```

So, a ternary conditional operation is of the form:

```py
expression1 if expression2 else expression3
```

`expression3` will be lazily evaluated (that is, evaluated only if `expression2` is false in a boolean context). And because of the recursive definition, you can chain them indefinitely (though it may considered bad style.)

```py
expression1 if expression2 else expression3 if expression4 else expression5 # and so on
```

#### A note on usage:

Note that every `if` must be followed with an `else`. People learning list comprehensions and generator expressions may find this to be a difficult lesson to learn - the following will not work, as Python expects a third expression for an else:

```py
[expression1 if expression2 for element in iterable]
#                          ^-- need an else here
```

which raises a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.
So the above is either an incomplete piece of logic (perhaps the user expects a no-op in the false condition) or what may be intended is to use `expression2` as a filter - notes that the following is legal Python:

```py
[expression1 for element in iterable if expression2]
```

`expression2` works as a filter for the list comprehension, and is *not* a ternary conditional operator.

#### Alternative syntax for a more narrow case:

You may find it somewhat painful to write the following:

```py
expression1 if expression1 else expression2
```

`expression1` will have to be evaluated twice with the above usage. It can limit redundancy if it is simply a local variable. However, a common and performant Pythonic idiom for this use-case is to use `or`'s shortcutting behavior:

```py
expression1 or expression2
```

which is equivalent in semantics. Note that some style-guides may limit this usage on the grounds of clarity - it does pack a lot of meaning into very little syntax.

Comment: `expression1 or expression2` being similar and with the same drawbacks/positives as `expression1 || expression2` in javascript

Comment: Thanks, @selurvedu - it can be confusing until you get it straight. I learned the hard way, so your way might not be as hard. ;) Using if without the else, at the end of a generator expression or list comprehension will filter the iterable. In the front, it's a ternary conditional operation, and requires the else. Cheers!!

Comment: @AaronHall Although your use of metasyntactic `expressionN` for all instances is consistent, it might be easier to understand with naming that distinguished the conditional test expression from the two result expressions; eg, `result1 if condition else result2`. This is especially evident when nesting (aka chaining): `result1 if condition1 else result2 if condition2 else result3`. See how much better that reads this way?

Comment: @tchrist thanks for the review - if you look at the revision history, this post currently has two revisions. Most of my other answers, especially the top ones, have been revisited again and again. This answer never gets my attention because the community wiki status gives me no credit for the content, and so I never see any votes on it. As I don't really have time for an edit on this right now, frog knows when it will come to my attention again in the future. I can see you've edited the top answer, so feel free to borrow/quote my material from this post in that one (and cite me if apropos!)

Answer (score 43):

One of the alternatives to Python's [conditional expression](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html)

```
"yes" if boolean else "no"
```

is the following:

```
{True: "yes", False: "no"}[boolean]
```

which has the following nice extension:

```
{True: "yes", False: "no", None: "maybe"}[boolean_or_none]
```

The shortest alternative remains

```
("no", "yes")[boolean]
```

which works because `issubclass(bool, int)`.

Careful, though: the alternative to

```
yes() if boolean else no()
```

is *not*

```
(no(), yes())[boolean]  # bad: BOTH no() and yes() are called
```

but

```
(no, yes)[boolean]()
```

This works fine as long as `no` and `yes` are to be called with exactly the same parameters. If they are not, like in

```
yes("ok") if boolean else no()  # (1)
```

or in

```
yes("ok") if boolean else no("sorry")  # (2)
```

then a similar alternative either does not exist (1) or is hardly viable (2). (In rare cases, depending on the context, something like

```
msg = ("sorry", "ok")[boolean]
(no, yes)[boolean](msg)
```

could make sense.)

<sub>Thanks to Radek Rojík for his comment</sub>

---

Addendum:

A special case of boolean indexing is when you need a single character. E.g.:

```
sign = '+-'[n < 0]
```

And finally, the plural `s`:

```
print(f"total: {n} item{'s'[n==1:]}")
```

Answer (score 34):

As already answered, yes, there is a ternary operator in Python:

```
<expression 1> if <condition> else <expression 2>
```

In many cases `<expression 1>` is also used as Boolean evaluated `<condition>`. Then you can use [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

```py
a = 0
b = 1

# Instead of this:
x = a if a else b
# Evaluates as 'a if bool(a) else b'

# You could use short-circuit evaluation:
x = a or b
```

One big pro of short-circuit evaluation is the possibility of chaining more than two expressions:

```py
x = a or b or c or d or e
```

When working with functions it is more different in detail:

```py
# Evaluating functions:
def foo(x):
    print('foo executed')
    return x


def bar(y):
    print('bar executed')
    return y


def blubb(z):
    print('blubb executed')
    return z


# Ternary Operator expression 1 equals to False
print(foo(0) if foo(0) else bar(1))
''' foo and bar are executed once
foo executed
bar executed
1
'''

# Ternary Operator expression 1 equals to True
print(foo(2) if foo(2) else bar(3))
''' foo is executed twice!
foo executed
foo executed
2
'''

# Short-circuit evaluation second equals to True
print(foo(0) or bar(1) or blubb(2))
''' blubb is not executed
foo executed
bar executed
1
'''

# Short-circuit evaluation third equals to True
print(foo(0) or bar(0) or blubb(2))
'''
foo executed
bar executed
blubb executed
2
'''

# Short-circuit evaluation all equal to False
print(foo(0) or bar(0) or blubb(0))
''' Result is 0 (from blubb(0)) because no value equals to True
foo executed
bar executed
blubb executed
0
'''
```

PS: Of course, a short-circuit evaluation is not a ternary operator, but often the ternary is used in cases where the short circuit would be enough. It has a better readability and can be chained.

Answer (score 32):

Simulating the Python ternary operator.

For example

```
a, b, x, y = 1, 2, 'a greather than b', 'b greater than a'
result = (lambda:y, lambda:x)[a > b]()
```

Output:

```
'b greater than a'
```

Comment: Why not simply `result = (y, x)[a < b]` Why do you uses `lambda` function **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Because on "compliated" expressions, e. g. involving a function call etc., this would be executed in both cases. This might not be wanted.

Comment: The use of `lambda` functions is an overkill for this question

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan In short, this implements the so-called “**short-circuit evaluation**”. Generally, `P ? x : y` or `x if P else y` can be written as `(lambda:y, lambda:x)[P]()` — but I doubt it has better performance and thus its necessity.

Answer (score 30):

```
a if condition else b
```

Just memorize this pyramid if you have trouble remembering:

```
     condition
  if           else
a                   b
```

Answer (score 30):

[Vinko Vrsalovic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator/394814#394814) is good enough. There is only one more thing:

> Note that conditionals are an *expression*, not a *statement*. This means you can't use assignment statements or `pass` or other **statements** within a conditional **expression**

#### Walrus operator in Python 3.8

After the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) was introduced in Python 3.8, something changed.

```
(a := 3) if True else (b := 5)
```

gives `a = 3` and `b is not defined`,

```
(a := 3) if False else (b := 5)
```

gives `a is not defined` and `b = 5`, and

```
c = (a := 3) if False else (b := 5)
```

gives `c = 5`, `a is not defined` and `b = 5`.

Even if this may be ugly, **assignments** can be done **inside** conditional expressions after Python 3.8. Anyway, it is still better to use normal `if` **statement** instead in this case.

Comment: In the first example: `(a := 3) if True else (b := 5)` actually it's a redundant first walrus operator. This will do: `a = 3 if True else (b := 5)`

Comment: @AndrewAnderson No it's not redundant. You should compare both the first and the second examples. You can combine them and consider this: `(a := 3) if x else (b := 5)`, you always get either `a` or `b` assigned, not both. However, consider `a = 3 if x else (b := 5)`, when `x == False`, you will get `a = 5` and `b = 5`, where both them are assigned.

Comment: Yes, that's correct :). I considered this only for `x=True` case which is of course is limited.

Comment: Because we don't really write down this code `if True else`, the reason of the first example is only compared with other examples.

Answer (score 28):

The ternary conditional operator simply allows testing a condition in a single line replacing the multiline if-else making the code compact.

#### Syntax:

> [on_true] if [expression] else [on_false]

#### 1- Simple Method to use ternary operator:

```
# Program to demonstrate conditional operator
a, b = 10, 20
# Copy value of a in min if a < b else copy b
min = a if a < b else b
print(min)  # Output: 10
```

#### 2- Direct Method of using tuples, Dictionary, and lambda:

```
# Python program to demonstrate ternary operator
a, b = 10, 20
# Use tuple for selecting an item
print( (b, a) [a < b] )
# Use Dictionary for selecting an item
print({True: a, False: b} [a < b])
# lambda is more efficient than above two methods
# because in lambda  we are assure that
# only one expression will be evaluated unlike in
# tuple and Dictionary
print((lambda: b, lambda: a)[a < b]()) # in output you should see three 10
```

#### 3- Ternary operator can be written as nested if-else:

```
# Python program to demonstrate nested ternary operator
a, b = 10, 20
print ("Both a and b are equal" if a == b else "a is greater than b"
        if a > b else "b is greater than a")
```

Above approach can be written as:

```
# Python program to demonstrate nested ternary operator
a, b = 10, 20
if a != b:
    if a > b:
        print("a is greater than b")
    else:
        print("b is greater than a")
else:
    print("Both a and b are equal")
# Output: b is greater than a
```

Comment: Note that the ternary operator is smaller (in memory) and faster than the nested if.  Also, your nested `if-else` isn't actually a rewrite of the ternary operator, and will produce different output for select values of a and b (specifically if one is a type which implements a weird `__ne__` method).

Answer (score 27):

You can do this:

```
[condition] and [expression_1] or [expression_2];
```

Example:

```
print(number%2 and "odd" or "even")
```

This would print "odd" if the number is odd or "even" if the number is even.

---

**The result:** If condition is true, exp_1 is executed, else exp_2 is executed.

**Note:** 0, None, False, emptylist, and emptyString evaluates as False.

And any data other than 0 evaluates to True.

### Here's how it works:

If the condition [condition] becomes "True", then expression_1 will be evaluated, but not expression_2.

If we "and" something with 0 (zero), the result will always to be false. So in the below statement,

```
0 and exp
```

The expression *exp* won't be evaluated at all since "and" with 0 will always evaluate to zero and there is no need to evaluate the expression. This is how the compiler itself works, in all languages.

In

```
1 or exp
```

the expression *exp* won't be evaluated at all since "or" with 1 will always be 1. So it won't bother to evaluate the expression exp since the result will be 1 anyway (compiler optimization methods).

But in case of

```
True and exp1 or exp2
```

The second expression exp2 won't be evaluated since `True and exp1` would be True when exp1 isn't false.

Similarly in

```
False and exp1 or exp2
```

The expression *exp1* won't be evaluated since False is equivalent to writing 0 and doing "and" with 0 would be 0 itself, but after exp1 since "or" is used, it will evaluate the expression exp2 after "or".

---

**Note:-** This kind of branching using "or" and "and" can only be used when the expression_1 doesn't have a Truth value of False (or 0 or None or emptylist [ ] or emptystring ' '.) since if expression_1 becomes False, then the expression_2 will be evaluated because of the presence "or" between exp_1 and exp_2.

**In case you still want to make it work for all the cases regardless of what exp_1 and exp_2 truth values are, do this:**

```
[condition] and ([expression_1] or 1) or [expression_2];
```

Comment: If you want to use that in the context of `x = [condition] and ([expression_1] or 1) or [expression_2]` and `expression_1` evaluates to false, `x` will be `1`, not `expression_1`. Use the accepted answer.

Answer (score 26):

More a tip than an answer (I don't need to repeat the obvious for the hundredth time), but I sometimes use it as a one-liner shortcut in such constructs:

```
if conditionX:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('nah')
```

, becomes:

```
print('yes') if conditionX else print('nah')
```

Some (many :) may frown upon it as unpythonic (even, Ruby-ish :), but I personally find it more natural - i.e., how you'd express it normally, plus a bit more visually appealing in large blocks of code.

Comment: I prefer `print( 'yes' if conditionX else 'nah' )` over your answer. :-)

Comment: That is if you want to `print()` in both cases - and it looks a bit more pythonic, I have to admit :) But what if the expressions/functions are not the same - like `print('yes') if conditionX else True` - to get the `print()` only in truthy `conditionX `

Comment: To add to Frederick99's remark, another reason to avoid `print('yes') if conditionX else print('nah')` is that it gives a SyntaxError in Python2.

Comment: The only reason it gives a syntax error is because in Python 2 print is a statement - `print "yes"`, while in Python 3 it is a function - `print("yes")`. That can be resolved by either using it as a statement, or better - `from future import print_function`.

Answer (score 16):

Many programming languages derived from [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) usually have the following syntax of the ternary conditional operator:

```
<condition> ? <expression1> : <expression2>
```

At first, the Python's [benevolent dictator for life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life) (I mean [Guido van Rossum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum), of course) rejected it (as non-Pythonic style), since it's quite hard to understand for people not used to C language. Also, the colon sign **`:`** already has many uses in Python. After **PEP 308** was approved, Python finally received its own shortcut conditional expression (what we use now):

```
<expression1> if <condition> else <expression2>
```

So, firstly it evaluates the condition. If it returns `True`, **expression1** will be evaluated to give the result, otherwise **expression2** will be evaluated. Due to [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) mechanics – only one expression will be executed.

Here are some examples (conditions will be evaluated from left to right):

```
pressure = 10
print('High' if pressure < 20 else 'Critical')

# Result is 'High'
```

Ternary operators can be chained in series:

```
pressure = 5
print('Normal' if pressure < 10 else 'High' if pressure < 20 else 'Critical')

# Result is 'Normal'
```

The following one is the same as previous one:

```
pressure = 5

if pressure < 20:
    if pressure < 10:
        print('Normal')
    else:
        print('High')
else:
    print('Critical')

# Result is 'Normal'
```

Answer (score 15):

*Yes*, Python have a ternary operator, here is the syntax and an example code to demonstrate the same :)

```
#[On true] if [expression] else[On false]
# if the expression evaluates to true then it will pass On true otherwise On false

a = input("Enter the First Number ")
b = input("Enter the Second Number ")

print("A is Bigger") if a>b else print("B is Bigger")
```

Comment: I have added a one line statement example to check which number is big to elaborate it further

Comment: `print` is really not a good choice, as this will give a SyntaxError in Python2.

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille here I used print() function not print statement, print function is for Python 3 while print statement is for Python 2

Comment: The question has already been asked on SO, just try it with Python 2 and you will see by yourself. 'print('hello') is a perfectly valid syntax in Python 2.7, but the way it is parsed makes your code above throw a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 12):

Other answers correctly talk about the Python ternary operator. I would like to complement by mentioning a scenario for which the ternary operator is often used, but for which there is a better idiom. This is the scenario of using a default value.

Suppose we want to use `option_value` with a default value if it is not set:

```
run_algorithm(option_value if option_value is not None else 10)
```

or, if `option_value` is never set to a falsy value (`0`, `""`, etc.), simply

```
run_algorithm(option_value if option_value else 10)
```

However, in this case an ever better solution is simply to write

```
run_algorithm(option_value or 10)
```

Comment: A valuable complement, but I disagree: `option_value or 10` is *not* better than `option_value if option_value is not None else 10`. It is shorter, indeed, but looks weird to me and may lead to bugs. What happens if `option_value = 0`, for instance? The first snippet will run `run_algorithm(0)` because `option_value` is not `None`. The second and third snippets, however, will run `run_algorithm(10)` because `0` is a falsy. The two snippets are not equivalent, and hence one is not better than the other. And explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @ruancomelli: Good point. I've modified the answer to reflect that correction.

Comment: As for it looking weird, I wonder if it looked weird to you because you noticed the imprecision (that it was not really equivalent). To me it sounds natural because it reminds me saying in English: "Use this or that (if the first option is unavailable)". But of course that is subjective. It is useful to know it does not look natural to everybody.

Comment: Much better! And thanks for the explanation regarding the "or"-idiom. It looks weird to me because I tend to think of `or` as a function mapping two arguments to a boolean, so I expect it to return either `True` or `False` (this happens in many other programming languages). But "use this or that" is a nice mnemonic and will definitely help me (and hopefully others) to remember this pattern.

Answer (score 12):

The syntax for the ternary operator in Python is:

`[on_true] if [expression] else [on_false]`

Using that syntax, here is how we would rewrite the code above using Python’s ternary operator:

```py
game_type = 'home'
shirt = 'white' if game_type == 'home' else 'green'
```

It's still pretty clear, but much shorter. Note that the expression could be any type of expression, including a function call, that returns a value that evaluates to True or False.

Answer (score 10):

Python has a ternary form for assignments; however there may be even a shorter form that people should be aware of.

It's very common to need to assign to a variable one value or another depending on a condition.

```
>>> li1 = None
>>> li2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>>
>>> if li1:
...     a = li1
... else:
...     a = li2
...
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

^ This is the long form for doing such assignments.

Below is the ternary form. But this isn't the most succinct way - see the last example.

```
>>> a = li1 if li1 else li2
>>>
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

With Python, you can simply use `or` for alternative assignments.

```
>>> a = li1 or li2
>>>
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

The above works since `li1` is `None` and the interpreter treats that as False in logic expressions. The interpreter then moves on and evaluates the second expression, which is not `None` and it's not an empty list - so it gets assigned to *a*.

This also works with empty lists. For instance, if you want to assign `a` whichever list has items.

```
>>> li1 = []
>>> li2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>>
>>> a = li1 or li2
>>>
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Knowing this, you can simply such assignments whenever you encounter them. This also works with strings and other iterables. You could assign `a` whichever string isn't empty.

```
>>> s1 = ''
>>> s2 = 'hello world'
>>>
>>> a = s1 or s2
>>>
>>> a
'hello world'
>>>
```

I always liked the C ternary syntax, but Python takes it a step further!

I understand that some may say this isn't a good stylistic choice, because it relies on mechanics that aren't immediately apparent to all developers. I personally disagree with that viewpoint. Python is a syntax-rich language with lots of idiomatic tricks that aren't immediately apparent to the dabbler. But the more you learn and understand the mechanics of the underlying system, the more you appreciate it.

Comment: Something seems to be missing near *"simply such assignments"*.

Comment: "Simplify" such assignments =) @PeterMortensen

Comment: Very interesting! Two questions: 1) Clearly, if exactly one of `li1` and `li2` is truthy, then `li1 or li2` will return its value. If `bool(li1) ` returns the same value as `bool(li2)`, will `li1 or li2` consistently evaluate to be either one or the other (perhabs by position)? 2) how can you interpret what returns from `li1 and li2`? I can't make sense of it with my test cases.

Comment: @TimH: 1) The right hand *or* subexpressions of the assignment are interpreted left to right. If the first one is truthy, that's the one that gets assigned to the var. If it isn't truthy, the second one is assigned. 2) using the *and* operation wouldn't be like some sort of *ternary* operation as this answer discusses.

Answer (score 7):

Pythonic way of doing the things:

```
"true" if var else "false"
```

But there always exists a different way of doing a ternary condition too:

```
"true" and var or "false"
```

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways. The simplest one is to use the condition inside the "print" method.

You can use

```
print("Twenty" if number == 20 else "Not twenty")
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
if number == 20:
    print("Twenty")
else:
    print("Not twenty")
```

In this way, more than two statements are also possible to print. For example:

```
if number == 20:
    print("Twenty")
elif number < 20:
    print("Lesser")
elif 30 > number > 20:
    print("Between")
else:
    print("Greater")
```

can be written as:

```
print("Twenty" if number == 20 else "Lesser" if number < 20 else "Between" if 30 > number > 20 else "Greater")
```

Answer (score 3):

The **if else-if** version can be written as:

```
sample_set="train" if "Train" in full_path else ("test" if "Test" in full_path else "validation")
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it has, but it's different from C-syntax-like programming languages (which is `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`

In Python, it goes like this: `value_if_true if condition else value_if_false`

Example: `even_or_odd = "even" if x % 2 == 0 else "odd"`

Answer (score 1):

*A neat way to chain multiple operators:*

```
f = lambda x,y: 'greater' if x > y else 'less' if y > x else 'equal'

array = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)]

for a in array:
  x, y = a[0], a[1]
  print(f(x,y))

# Output is:
#   equal,
#   less,
#   greater,
#   equal
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Python has a ternary conditional operator, also known as the conditional expression or the ternary operator. The syntax of the ternary operator in Python is:

```
value_if_true if condition else value_if_false
```

Here's an example to illustrate its usage:

```
x = 5
result = "Even" if (x % 2 == 0) else "Odd"
print(result)
```

In this example, the condition x % 2 == 0 checks if x is divisible by 2. If the condition is True, the value "Even" is assigned to the variable result. Otherwise, the value "Odd" is assigned. The output will be:

```
Odd
```

It is a good idea to use parenthesis, in order to increase readability, when working with medium complexity operations:

```
"Even" if (x % 2 == 0) else "Odd"
```

Instead of:

```
"Even" if x % 2 == 0 else "Odd"
```

The ternary operator is a concise way to write simple conditional expressions in a single line. It can be particularly useful when assigning values or constructing expressions based on conditions. However, for more complex conditions or longer expressions, if possible it's generally better to use if-else statements for improved readability.

Answer (score 0):

I find the default Python syntax `val = a if cond else b` cumbersome, so sometimes I do this:

```
iif = lambda (cond, a, b): a if cond else b
# So I can then use it like:
val = iif(cond, a, b)
```

Of course, it has the downside of always evaluating both sides (*a* and *b*), but the syntax is way clearer to me.

Comment: This seems to be twice the amount of work, more RAM usage and more obfuscated than the simpler `val = a if cond else b` statement.

Comment: Also both `a` and `b` get evaluated here every time, unlike in `a if cond else b`

Comment: According to PEP8 assigning lambda to variable is a code smell. Lambda should be used only as inplace function.

Answer (score 0):

I have data coming from a device as a string and leaving it as a rebuild string. Conditional expression need to be limited by (). This allow to have multiple conditions to build the string in one line. If not it seems like whatever after the "else" will be accounted.

```
    d0 = "-679 58 1029"
    d1 = d0.split(" ")

    strg = (d1[0][:-2] if len(d1[0])>= 3 else "0") + " " +d1[0][-2:]+ " "+ (d1[1][:-2] if len(d1[1])>= 3 else "0") + " " + d1[1][-2:] + " " +d1[2]
    print(strg)
```