# What's the best way to replace the ternary operator in Python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ternary conditional operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python)

If I have some code like:

```
x = foo ? 1 : 2
```

How should I translate it to Python? Can I do this?

```
if foo:
  x = 1
else:
  x = 2
```

Will x still be in scope outside the if / then blocks? Or do I have to do something like this?

```
x = None
if foo:
  x = 1
else:
  x = 2
```

Comment: One way to replace it is to call it by its correct name.  In Python it's the "conditional expression".  In C it's the "conditional operator".  In Java it's the "conditional operator".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the ternary operator(formally [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)) in Python 2.5+.

```
x = 1 if foo else 2
```

Comment: Only, please call it the conditional expression, since that's what it is.

Comment: @Adriano Varoli Piazza @S.Lott added that to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

A nice python trick is using this:

```
foo = ["ifFalse","ifTrue"][booleanCondition]
```

It creates a 2 membered list, and the boolean becomes either 0 (false) or 1 (true), which picks the correct member.
Not very readable, but pythony :)

Comment: I would neither readable, nor pythonic, but it's still something I use all the time... if you're doing this trick, do it as a tuple:  (trueFunc, falseFunc)[bool(condition)]

Comment: The Python 2.5 conditional expression will evaluate only ONE of the trueFunc, falseFunc expressions. This formula evaluates both.

Comment: Use (booleanCondition and [trueFunc] or [falseFunc])[0].

Comment: x = [1, 2][foo]

Answer (score 5):

The Ternary operator [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643983/whats-the-best-way-to-replace-the-ternary-operator-in-python/644001#644001) is only available from Python 2.5. From the [WeekeePeedeea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation):

> Though it had been delayed for several
>   years by disagreements over syntax, a
>   ternary operator for Python was
>   approved as Python Enhancement
>   Proposal 308 and was added to the 2.5
>   release in September 2006.
>
> Python's ternary operator differs from
>   the common ?: operator in the order of
>   its operands; the general form is `op1
>   if condition else op2`. This form
>   invites considering op1 as the normal
>   value and op2 as an exceptional case.
>
> Before 2.5, one could use the ugly
>   syntax `(lambda x:op2,lambda
>   x:op1)[condition]()` which also takes
>   care of only evaluating expressions
>   which are actually needed in order to
>   prevent side effects.

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate of [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/python-ternary-operator)

I use this (although I'm waiting for somebody to downvote or comment if it is incorrect):

```
x = foo and 1 or 2
```

Comment: That works in this case, but it can be dangerous in general:
   x = foo and bar or baz
will produce baz if foo is true and bar is false, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: ah, got it.  I've used this for a while, and wasn't quite sure why it wasn't an accepted method.  I can see that now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still using 2.4 in one of my projects and have come across this a few times.  The most elegant solution I've see for this is:

```
x = {True: 1, False: 2}[foo is not None]
```

I like this because it represents a more clear boolean test than using a list with the index values 0 and 1 to get your return value.

Comment: "not not foo" would be better -- empty lists, zeroes and whatnot should also evaluate to False.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
val = float(raw_input("Age: "))
status = ("working","retired")[val>65]
print "You should be",status
```

though it is not very *pythonic*

(the other options are closer to C/PERL, but this involves more tuple magic)